# Synapse - The column name is invalid. Column name cannot contain these character:[,;{}()\\n\\t=]

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I've got a basic Synapse Pipeline which moves data from a SQL Server table to a Parquet file in blob storage. When running the pipeline it fails with the following error message:

```
{
    "dataRead": 45,
    "dataWritten": 0,
    "filesWritten": 0,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 1,
    "rowsRead": 1,
    "rowsCopied": 1,
    "copyDuration": 4,
    "throughput": 0.011,
    "errors": [
        {
            "Code": 21018,
            "Message": "ErrorCode=ParquetInvalidColumnName,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The column name is invalid. Column name cannot contain these character:[,;{}()\\n\\t=],Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
            "EventType": 0,
            "Category": 5,
            "Data": {},
            "MsgId": null,
            "ExceptionType": null,
            "Source": null,
            "StackTrace": null,
            "InnerEventInfos": []
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (UK South)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.06666666666666667,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "region": "UK South"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                "region": "UK South"
            },
            "status": "Failed",
            "start": "2022-03-25T09:50:19.7461477Z",
            "duration": 4,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 2
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 1,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                            "workingDuration": 0,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 0
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 2,
                "timeToFirstByte": 0,
                "transferDuration": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

To clarify, none of the table column names actually contain any "invalid characters". They are all just A-Z, no space. Also the pipeline moved about 3GB of data before failing. If I change the SQL query to fetch 10m rows instead of 72m rows, the pipeline runs perfectly fine.

I think the error message is bogus, and this is actually failing because of something data related. Are there no advanced debugging options in Synapse pipeline which can help me identify where / why this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

- As per this Github [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-parquet.md#error-code-parquetinvalidcolumnname) , the resolution given for this kind of issue is to **Add or modify the column mapping to make the sink column name valid.**
- Also, white space is not allowed in parquet format. Please refer  the Note in below document.
  [Parquet format in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet#dataset-properties).
- A few workarounds for this error can be referred from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452885/adf-copy-activity-fails-csv-to-parquet-when-csv-has-space-in-header-column).

Comment: I do not have spaces or invalid characters in the headers. All column names are A-Z characters only.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, I have a similar problems and the issue was Excel (or the creator of the excel file) was placing special characters between words. Like DelayDays has a carriage return between the 2 words. We had to manually change the parquet file column name in the Mappings to get it to work. The error message is not helpful